# Black spots on basil leaves

Tags: diseases, basil

I just got these basil plants a week ago and now they seem to have these black spots on them. All three of the plants are in the same general area, and all of them have the same symptoms.

I recently had some rain, but temperatures didn't seem that bad. I also have some cuttings from the same plants that don't have these signs and are sitting indoors.

Many of the affected leaves were removed to help stop it from spreading, but at this point every leaf is affected.

Here's some pictures:
[image: whole basil plant]

[image: Closeup of first picture.]

Comment: This does not seem a basil